Flutter: global theme not working on alternative route
I defined a global theme which is called in my main.dart. This is the code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'package:my_app/blocs/login_bloc/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:my_app/view/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:my_app/theme/themes.dart';
import 'package:my_app/view/screens/login_page.dart'

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Firebase Auth',
        theme: Themes.lightTheme(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => const LoginPage(),
          '/home': (context) => const HomePage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

When I navigate to LoginPage() in the app then the theme Themes.lightTheme() is used. But when I reach HomePage(), the theme won't be used.
This is home_page.dart:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../blocs/login_bloc/login_bloc.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    String userId = Global.userId;

    return Theme(
      data: theme,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

What am I missing? It really appears that the issue lies within the routing. Is maybe Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/'); the problem and is there an alternative which I should use?

If you think "It really appears that the issue lies within the routing" then remove named routes and try Navigator.push(     context,     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),   ) .

At least when I switched the to pages in main.dart so that / routes to HomePage() and /home to LoginPage(), the theme was applied only on Homepage(). Sadly your recommendation didn't make a difference.

When you navigate to the HomePage, it seems that the global theme is not being applied. Now the issue is the Theme widget you're using in HomePage. In the HomePage, you have:
return Theme(
  data: theme,
  child: Scaffold(
    // ...
  ),
);

Here, you're manually setting the theme for HomePage, which can cause conflicts or override the global theme if not done properly.
Avoid manually setting the theme in HomePage since Theme.of(context) should already be using the global theme if everything is set up correctly.
// You can still access the theme here if needed, but no need to manually wrap it.
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Home'),
  ),
  body: ...,
);

Please make sure that there are no other Theme widgets or ThemeData that might override the global theme.

That didn't make a difference either, but at least I removed the unnecessary Theme-Widget :)
